# Can't get data from object array | React.js - openweatherAPI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, openweathermap

I fetch data from openweatherAPI by using react-redux Toolkit. I can get name but when I want to get main.temp it gives an error

> typeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'temp')

```
export const fetchDefault = createAsyncThunk('weather/getWeather', async (selectedCity) => {
const res = await axios(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${selectedCity}&appid=6d735f036884219e3a12eeb6f7bf6f93`)
return res.data});
```

ExtraReducers

```
[fetchDefault.fulfilled]: (state , action) => {
        state.item = action.payload;
        console.log(state.item)
    },
```

It works if I `return res.data.main` but this time cant get name .

index.js

```
const getCity  = useSelector((state) => state.weather.item);
{getCity.main.temp} // Gives Error..
```

Array looks like this..

```
    {
 "weather": [
   {
     "id": 802,
     "main": "Clouds",
     "description": "scattered clouds",
   }
 ],
 "main": {
   "temp": 300.15,
   "pressure": 1007,
   "humidity": 74,
   "temp_min": 300.15,
   "temp_max": 300.15
 },
 "wind": {
   "speed": 3.6,
   "deg": 160
 "id": 2172797,
 "name": "Cairns",
 "cod": 200
 }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your reducer saves `action.payload` into `state.item`, so I think the `useSelector` should return `state.item.name` for `getCity` (assuming that you want to access the city's name with that selector).

Alternatively, you can create a selector for `state.item`, and access everything through that.

Btw, your reducer should return a value, so assuming that state was an object initially, it should look like:

```
[fetchDefault.fulfilled]: (state , action) => {
    return {...state, item: action.payload}        
},
```

Comment: thanks for answer but it still gives same error . I can easily get name but cant get temprature which is (getCity.main.temp or weather.id ) I don't know why ...
In fetchDefault I tried return res.data.main instead of res.data it worked but cant get name at this time

Comment: Can you share the code of the project?

The error message is understandable, because lot's of things doesn't make sense here.

You need to change the extraReducer because the original one doesn't return anything.

Reading state.weather.item in the useSelector also doesn't make sense. In fetchDefault you should return res.data. That one is good.